# I need to convert all the elements in my list to int in python when i used map it doesn't work

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am reading numbers from a file and storing it in a list numbers and want to convert all the elements in the list to be converted to int

```
num=[int(i) for i in numbers]
```

error msg:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

I also tried using `map`

```
num = list(map(int, numbers))
print("The integer list \n",num)
```

error msg:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: You have an iterable of lists, have you tried to print it what numbers is?

Comment: well the error says it all, what you are feeding to `int()` is not valid. Check what it actually is!

Comment: You say you are reading from a file. Can you show that code? Are you opening with the `rb` option?

Answer (score 0):

**class int(x, base=10)**

> Return an integer object constructed from a number or string x, or
>   return 0 if no arguments are given. If x is a number, it can be a
>   plain integer, a long integer, or a floating point number.

It does not seem that all the elements in your list are valid.So maybe some of elements are like `a1` or they aren't `string`, you should check out your list.

Try to run this and you will find why it didn't work:

```
from datetime import datetime
s=['1',datetime.now(),'a1']   # your list

def convert_to_int(s):
    if isinstance(s,str):
        try:
            return int(s)
        except:
            print s, type(s)
            return None
    else:
        print s,type(s)
        return None

print list(map(convert_to_int,s))
```

Hope this helps.